# How to put multiple updates in a trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I hope you can help me here.
I am using MySQL + PhpMyAdmin and I have 2 tables in this problem.

Table 1: Accounts - id, account_name, website, etc. etc...
Table 2: Domains - id, domain_name, account_name

and I Inserted these queries into 2 triggers.

Before Update
update domains, accounts
set domains.account_name = NULL
where accounts.website != domains.domain_name

After Update
update domains, accounts
set domains.account_name = accounts.account_name
where domains.domain_name = main_accounts.website

With these, when I update something in the accounts table, it will automatically remove the account_name from domains table and put new account_name if a certain account is updated.

Images below will show example.
Tables not yet updated:
----------
**Accounts Table**
[image]

**Domains Table**
[image]
----------
----------
**Updated View.**
----------
----------
**Accounts Table**
[image]

**Domains Table**
[image]

So, on the second account table image, I have changed the domain and automatically, the domains table has been updated. I would want to make only 1 trigger that will contain those 2 update queries. I don't know if it's possible because after I complete this, I may also need to know how to update multiple different tables from 1 trigger. The reason why I ask is because I need to assign the account name for each sub-tables that are in use. Example, the main table is the accounts table and the sub tables that needs to be updated are:
domains.account_name
ip_address.account_name
phones.account_name
payments.account_name

So, I don't know if it's even possible to update those sub-tables under column "account_name" when the main table "accounts" is updated.

Thank you. I hope my question is clear. :D :D

Comment: maybe consider normalizing your structures so that you do not need to do this.  having said that, you can just put multiple statements in to the trigger one after the other.  strong word of caution - consider what happens if someone updates the 'lower' tables directly...

Comment: Thank you Randy for your comment. Unfortunately for some reason, I get a "MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax" error when I put it using ";" after each... Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can group multiple statements into a trigger with BEGIN and END.

Example:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON accounts
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- Statement one
    UPDATE domains
    SET domains.account_name = accounts.account_name
    WHERE domains.domain_name = main_accounts.website;
    -- Statement two
    UPDATE another_table
    SET another_table.column_name = accounts.account_name
    WHERE another_table.domain_name = accounts.some_column;
    -- More UPDATE statements
END$$
```

Comment: Hello, thank you.. I tried it and it created a trigger but for some reason, it only saved/recorded the first statement. the second statement was not there when I opened the trigger...