# Mysql 2 updates in the same trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have 2 tables route and loc. When either the drivername or rt_num changes in the route table I need to update the loc table. I have tried all day playing with the following code. Each UPDATE statement works as a trigger by it self. I am not sure if it can be done at all.

```
    DELIMITER |
    CREATE TRIGGER `add2` AFTER UPDATE ON `route`
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
    AFTER UPDATE ON `route`;

    UPDATE loc
      SET drivername = new.driver_d_name
      WHERE rt_nanme = old.rt_num;

   UPDATE loc
    SET rt_nanme = new.rt_num
    WHERE rt_nanme = old.rt_num;    

    END;
    |   
    DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you repeating the `after update` statement?

In addition, you don't need two update statements.  So:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `add2` AFTER UPDATE ON `route`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

    UPDATE loc
        SET drivername = new.driver_d_name,
            rt_nanme = new.rt_num
    WHERE rt_nanme = old.rt_num;

END;$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff works like a charm. I am new at this at age 65 and I tend to way over complicate things.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with [having multiple updates in a single trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29855711/how-to-put-multiple-updates-in-a-trigger).  But your trigger has a syntax problem, and it is this which is probably causing the failure.  Try this instead:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER `add2` AFTER UPDATE ON `route`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

    UPDATE loc
    SET drivername = new.driver_d_name
    WHERE rt_nanme = old.rt_num;

    UPDATE loc
    SET rt_nanme = new.rt_num
    WHERE rt_nanme = old.rt_num;    

END
```

Answer (score 0):

before update compare it with old value

```
DELIMITER |
    CREATE TRIGGER `add2` AFTER UPDATE ON `route`
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
       IF(new.driver_d_name!=old.driver_d_name) THEN
            UPDATE loc
            SET drivername = new.driver_d_name
            WHERE rt_nanme = old.rt_num;
        END IF;
       IF(new.rt_num!=old.rt_num) THEN
           UPDATE loc
            SET rt_nanme = new.rt_num
            WHERE rt_nanme = old.rt_num;    
          END IF;
    END;
    |   
    DELIMITER ;
```